# Atom and Visual Studio Code editors: Numpad behavior

Tags: linux, atom-editor, numpad

I searched a bit here and in google, but I didn't find any solution for this issue. Probably I am not searching with right phrases, but hope you get what I mean.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. My NumLock is always off. I am not using these digits while coding, and instead most of all I use the “End” button, which in combination with four navigation buttons (the arrows) is quite useful for me. I am using Sublime and there using Numpad’s end is as follows:

- “End” — brings the cursor to the end of the line;
- “Shift + End” — selects all from cursor position to the end of the line.

This is what I am expecting as a behavior. Soon I installed Atom and Visual Studio Code and while typed, I got the following behavior (NumLock — off):

- “End” — brings the cursor to the end of the line;
- “Shift + End” — prints number one (a digit “1”).

My question is: Is there any way to make Numpad’s “End” to behave like the case with Sublime, described first?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

OK, got it. Here is the solution that worked for me:

[The AskUbuntu question: Shift + numeric keypad prints number (with NumLock off)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730083/shift-numeric-keypad-prints-number-with-numlock-off)

And especially:

> (…) an option in the system settings: *Keyboard > Advanced > Miscellaneous compatibility options > Shift with numeric keypad keys works as in MS Windows*. (…)

Answer (score 1):

@Askers answer is right, but since this option has been removed from the settings menu here is something that still works.

This is copied from: https://askubuntu.com/a/1170742/683

> For uBuntu 18.04, another options is to use Dconf-Editor, a powerful
>   GUI for most uBuntu settings. If not installed, open Terminal and
>   type:
>
> - `apt-get update`
> - `apt-get install dconf-editor -y`
>
> Open `dconf Editor`, then
>   `/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options`.
>
> On a fresh uBuntu installation, `Custom value` will be blank. Turn
>   `Use default value` OFF then:
>
> - insert `['numpad:microsoft']` (if blank) or
> - append `, 'numpad:microsoft'` (after whatever is there, if not blank)
>
> For example, `['caps:none', 'numpad:microsoft']` which both disables
>   Caps Lock and uses the NumPad as in Windows. Close `dconf Editor`, no
>   reboot required.